# LoadError: cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger/rack_handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

when i run `rake db:create` on staging server i got error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- phusion_passenger/rack_handler
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
```

Here is my **Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  # https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "capistrano", "~> 3.4"
  gem "passenger", ">= 5.0.25", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
end
```

I just wondering i just use passenger when develop locally why i got this error, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=Staging
```

`rake db:create` the default environment at least include `develop` environment. Because i just run this command locally i got `develop` and `test` environment database. So the error is obvious.